# I am new to ES and have a multi-match query in ES, and want to consider field based on its availability

Tags: elasticsearch

```
{
    "multi_match": {
      "query": "TEST",
      "fields": [
        "description.regexkeyword^1.0",
        "logical_name.regexkeyword^1.0",
        "logical_table_name.regexkeyword^1.0",
        "physical_name.regexkeyword^1.0",
        "presentation_name.regexkeyword^1.0",
        "table_name.regexkeyword^1.0"
      ],
      "type": "best_fields",
      "operator": "AND",
      "slop": 0,
      "prefix_length": 0,
      "max_expansions": 50,
      "lenient": false,
      "zero_terms_query": "NONE",
      "boost": 1
    }
  }
```

There is a field, i.e. `edited_description`, if in case `edited_description exists` in document then consider `edited_description.regexkeyword^1.0` else consider description, i.e. `description.regexkeyword^1.0`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't define an if condition in multi_match query. But what you can do is re-look your problem statement in a different way. I can re-look this as, that if in case `edited_description` and `description` both exists then the match in `edited_description` field should be given a higher preference.

This can achieved by setting slightly higher boost value for `edited_description` field.

```
{
  "multi_match": {
    "query": "TEST",
    "fields": [
      "description.regexkeyword^1.0",
      "edited_description.regexkeyword^1.2",
      "logical_name.regexkeyword^1.0",
      "logical_table_name.regexkeyword^1.0",
      "physical_name.regexkeyword^1.0",
      "presentation_name.regexkeyword^1.0",
      "table_name.regexkeyword^1.0"
    ],
    "type": "best_fields",
    "operator": "AND",
    "slop": 0,
    "prefix_length": 0,
    "max_expansions": 50,
    "lenient": false,
    "zero_terms_query": "NONE",
    "boost": 1
  }
}
```

This will result in documents having a match in `edited_description` to be ranked higher. You can adjust the boosting value to your needs.

Comment: Thank you @Opster ES Ninja Nishant, let's say i am searching based on text "abc" and both field edited_description and description are available but edited_description has value "xyz" and description has value "abc", in this case the document shouldn't come in the result. How can we achieve this because description field is like obsolete for me. I have to consider searching should always happen on edited_description if it is available.

Comment: I feel this can be better handled at indexing time. Whenever you are indexing value to `edited_description` index `null` to `description` field. This will always result a match in one field i.e. in `edited_description` if the document has been updated and in `description` if the document is not updated with `edited_description` yet.

Comment: description field is like first entered value to a field and edited_description is a subsequent changes made to field. So i can't make null to description field as i also have to track the very first value entered. Is there any other way i can achieve.